# Как "перевернуть" число с плавающей запятой, в отношении к setAlpha();?

Tags: java, android, float, android-view

Как сделать так называемый "реверс" для числа с плавающей запятой?

Например есть число с плавающей  запятой. Его диапазон от `0.0f` до `1.0f` . 
По дефолту число равно `0.0f` .

Когда происходит действие, оно увеличивается. `0.10f` `0.23f` `0.37f` `0.40f` и так до `1.0f`. То есть `0` стремится к `1`.

Есть метод для View `view.setAlpha(float);` , позволяющий установить прозрачность для `View` элемента. Если `0` - значит прозрачный, если `1` - значит видимый.

И когда `View` элемент снизу экрана начать тащить вверх экрана, нужно чтобы он становился прозрачным (`0.f`). А он наоборот становится видимым, из за того что туда `1.0f` вместо `0.f` приходит.

```
if (slideOffset > 0.0f && slideOffset < 1.0f) {

view.setAlpha(slideOffset);

} else {

view.setAlpha(slideOffset);

}
```

Comment: Наверное у вас slideOffset это int, вот он и округляется до 1

Comment: slideOffset это точно float. Всё работает как и положено. Нужно только сделать наоборот чтобы не от 0 к 1 стремилось значение, а от 1 к 0. Иначе я делаю элемент view видимым , вместо прозрачности.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это в библиотеке `'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'` в слушателе приходит значение `onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset)`

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы при увеличении `slideOffset` уменьшалась `Alpha`, используйте

```
view.setAlpha(1.0 - slideOffset);
```